# How to connect a Bluetooth network connection using the command line

Tags: windows-7, networking, command-line, bluetooth, netsh

I can enable a Local Area Network interface for my machine with the command

```
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" ENABLED
```

Is there an equivalent command to connect a bluetooth network connection?

I've tried

```
netsh interface set interface "Bluetooth" ENABLED
```

but it seems to have no effect, the connection remains disconnected.

I also tried

```
netsh interface set interface "Bluetooth" connect=CONNECTED
```

but this returns

> One or more essential parameters not specified

I know this Bluetooth connection is otherwise ok since I am able to connect using Control Panel > Network Connections, right-clicking on Bluetooth > Connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the command

```
netsh interface show interface
```

Does not show your interface, then you can't control it that way.

Just a guess, but it looks like you are trying to establish a Dial-Up network connection over Bluetooth.

This works for me:

```
C:\Users\me>rasdial "USSC Bluetooth Dial-up Connection"
Connecting to USSC Bluetooth Dial-up Connection...
Verifying username and password...
Registering your computer on the network...
Successfully connected to USSC Bluetooth Dial-up Connection.
Command completed successfully.

C:\Users\me>rasdial "USSC Bluetooth Dial-up Connection" /DISCONNECT
Command completed successfully.
```

Comment: Nice guess. 123

Answer (score 2):

If someone like me, was looking for PAN (Personal Area Network) via Bluetooth auto-connect, there is no native way that I have found. However, there exists three 3rd party solutions.

- Free. Mixed results, some commands did not work with my adapter:
  [Bluetooth Command Line Tools](http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/)
- Potentially free (depending on your hardware). Comes with 30 days trial, works well:
  [Toshiba Bluetooth Stack](http://support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?contentId=3461138)
- Non-free. Have not tried, but heard positive things:
  [BlueSoleil](http://www.bluesoleil.com/index.aspx)